# How to get the entire process.StandardOutput as a string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, cmd, redirectstandardoutput

I have the below code.

```
        Process compiler = new Process();
        compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = ("/C git push gitlab --delete branch");
        compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        compiler.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        compiler.Start();
        string output = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        compiler.WaitForExit();
        compiler.Close();
```

I get only the `null` value in `string output`.But I got the below data in output screen.

> error: unable to delete 'branch': remote ref does not exist
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.company.com/test2.git'

Why i got the null value in the `output` string? Why did the **process** `compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` failed to fetch those line?

I got the output data in the console screen because I set `false` in `CreateNoWindow`. Else I would not get the data in console screen.

Anyone suggest the way to get the output screen data from the `Process.StandardOutPut`.

Comment: Because these lines were written into **stderr**, not **stdout**, I suspect.

Comment: @arrowd is correct. You also need to redirect (and read) `StandardError`

Comment: @arrowd is correct I got the output in stderr. Thanks lots :-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get a null value when you read StandardOutput is because the application has written nothing at that point in time.

There are two events associated with `Process` which you can subscribe to read the data - `OutputDataReceived and Exited`

[OutputDataReceived Documentation & Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Exited Documentation & Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Gururaj's first link shows an example.  Note some processes don't log information to stdout until after the process ends!  In those cases you won't get anything until it's completed.  E.g. Selenium Chrome Driver.

Comment: @JohnPeters - You're absolutely correct. In such cases Exited event can be used to get complete information once the application has exited gracefully. You may also want to check the Exit code if process exited without any issues or was it killed or something

Answer (score 0):

I get the desired output in `process.Standarderror`